# How to query Django model from views.py file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model named Search in my models.py file. I have made migrations and everything is working totally fine except one problem. In my views.py file I have created one variable called var1 which queries "search_query" field into the database, but unfortunately, it couldn't assign that variable.
Please help me how to access my model to work this line,

```
var1 = Search.objects.latest('search_query')
```

Here is my models.py file,

```
from django.db import models

class Search(models.Model):
    search_query = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

views.py file,

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests
from git_profile.forms import SearchForm
from git_profile.models import Search

def index(request):
    var1 = Search.objects.latest('search_query')
```

EDIT:

I want to replace 'var1' with this replacement 
`python 
user_profile = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/{0}'.format(str(v‌​‌​ar1))) 
content = dict() 
content['user'] = user_profile.json()`

but var1 can not be replaced by replacement field and API gives me weird error

Comment: There's a comma where there should be a dot.

Comment: Can you give a little insight of what you want to do  with your query ?

Comment: I want to replace 'var1' with this replacement ```python user_profile = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/{0}'.format(str(v‌​ar1))) 

content = dict() 

content['user'] = user_profile.json() 
```
but var1 can not be replaced by replacement field and API gives me weird error

Answer (score 3):

There is an useful search using boolean operator that you can use `from django.db.models import Q # filter using operators '&' or '|'`.

Example:

```
class RestaurantListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        if slug:
            queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(
                Q(category__iexact=slug) |
                Q(category__icontains=slug)
            )
        else:
            queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

For more information of using queryset, refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html

Cheers
Henry

Answer (score 1):

In your view you most create a Dictionary and assign the select variable to a property and the pass the dictionary to the view in this way:

```
def index(request):    
    var1 = Search.objects.latest('search_query').search_query
    context = {'property': var1 }
    return render(request, 'YOURVIEW', context)
```

and then access to the dictionary in the view:

```
{{ property.your_key}}
```

See more information in the Django App part 3 tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

I have had a hard time understanding what you're trying to do, however these are typical use cases.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests
from git_profile.forms import SearchForm
from git_profile.models import Search


def index(request):
    var1 = Search.objects.all()
    # do something with variable var1

# another example
def index(request, search_query):
    # as you can notice I'm expecting the parameter search_query, so make sure that in urls.py you define it properly.
    var1 = Search.objects.filter(search_query=search_query)
```

edit as per Klaus D.'s comment:

you're also missing a dot

```
def index(request):
    var1 = Search.objects.latest('search_query').search_query
    # do something with variable var1
```

Comment: I want to replace 'var1' with this replacement
```python
user_profile = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/{0}'.format(str(var1)))
content = dict()
content['user'] = user_profile.json()
```
but var1 can not be replaced by replacement field and API gives me weird